# Unable to verify the SHA256 checksum for Focal (20.04) LTS minimal cloud image

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, cloud, gnupg, signature

I'm attempting to follow the official [How to verify your Ubuntu download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#5-verify-the-sha256-checksum) tutorial to verify the checksum provided with the 20.04 minimal cloud image from [here](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/focal/release/).

I'm getting an error from the first command:

```
$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: not a detached signature
```

I don't think the checksum is being verified because of the error and I'm not having any luck finding a solution elsewhere. I have deleted and re-downloaded the files a couple of times, so it's not an issue with that.

Has anyone seen this before? Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1579649/how-to-fix-warning-not-a-detached-signature) at SuperUser SE community will help?

Comment: I did see this post when I was googling it, but I do not want to create a detached signature and I do not know why I'm getting a message like it expects one. I completed the exact same steps with the regular ubuntu server install files and did not get this output, I got the expected output per the first link I posted. Someone with a different computer in our house tried the steps and got the same issue as well. I think there may be something wrong with the files included with the cloud image, perhaps they signed it with the wrong signature?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Ubuntu Minimal SHA256SUMS are not signed using the `--detach-sign` (or `-b`) command, which would create the expected detached signature. Instead they are signed using the `--sign` (or `-s`) command, creating a self-contained signed document.

You can both check the signature and recover the signed document by using the `--decrypt` command (counterintuitive, I know).

```
$ gpg --decrypt SHA256SUMS.gpg
c3f4cd7464340015b2977da9fb96028263eb62dbf96b048984034d11791beb4c  ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img
73b2c5abc077b8778ce2e17511b606a2d076dc01047c54add62ee76e8c5df710  ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-lxd.tar.xz
e61af8d1932f683a90a5e6247af92c94a0b45a2e78c6c769320e2b12ffc10f46  ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.manifest
46f64b066e8f3db24fcf72376ff91e8ac0e5c29e4bde61c42a4ebc2ecb1fef55  ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-root.manifest
35a78bf1dd2438e95c0b7d3b0a0206e4c15289459588be42f9a271c5503ee4eb  ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz
ebd14a7963b884df3878e4ab0e6523d132fd332dbdb835d7d03f915d2961135b  ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.squashfs
46f64b066e8f3db24fcf72376ff91e8ac0e5c29e4bde61c42a4ebc2ecb1fef55  ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.squashfs.manifest
gpg: Signature made Thu 25 Mar 2021 12:06:00 PM PDT
gpg:                using RSA key 7FF3F408476CF100
gpg: Good signature from "Ubuntu Cloud Image Builder (Canonical Internal Cloud Image Builder) <ubuntu-cloudbuilder-noreply@canonical.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 4A3C E3CD 565D 7EB5 C810  E2B9 7FF3 F408 476C F100
```

If you want it to output the signed document, use the `--output FILENAME` option.